# Alert dialog using fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am developing an application with Fragments,i will explain with steps clearly?

1.In my application i am using two fragments one is right and other is left, i have implemented alert dialog in right fragment it is coming in center of screen.I don,t want to display the alert dialog in center of screen,it need to be display in the right fragment.

How i can achieve this guys.

Thanks.

Comment: This link with help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912181/simplest-yes-no-dialog-fragment