# Simplest yes/no dialog fragment

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I'd like to make a `dialog fragment` that asks "Are you sure?" with a "yes/no" reply.

I've looked at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog) and it's really verbose, going all over the place, explaining how to make advanced dialog boxes, but no intact code on making a simple 'hello world' kind of dialog box. Most tutorials utilize the deprecated dialog box system. The [official blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) seems to be unnecessarily complicated and difficult to understand.

So, what's the simplest way to create and display a really basic Alert Dialog? Bonus points if it's using the support library.

Comment: Also try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38500468/3496570

Answer (score 80, accepted):

A DialogFragment is really just a fragment that wraps a dialog. You can put any kind of dialog in there by creating and returning the dialog in the onCreateDialog() method of the DialogFragment.

Heres an example DialogFragment:

```
class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
    Context mContext;
    public MyDialogFragment() {
        mContext = getActivity();
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Really?");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
        //null should be your on click listener
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }
}
```

To create the dialog call:

```
new MyDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
```

And to dismiss the dialog from somewhere:

```
((MyDialogFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyDialog")).getDialog().dismiss();
```

All of that code will work perfectly with the support library, by just changing the imports to use the support library classes.

Comment: Thanks, but seems to cause the error `Unable to instantiate fragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public` if I exit and re-enter the application while the dialog is open. Added an empty constructor, but then got a null pointer on mContext.

Comment: @muz The Android system requires a `Fragment` class to have a constructor with **no parameters** in order to instantiate the fragment when it needs to. In a `Fragment` you have a reference to the activity where this fragment is used with the method `getActivity()`(use it instead of `mContext`). Also the fragment must be declared in its own java file or as an **inner static** class in another class. Otherwise Android will not be able to find your fragment to instantiate it.

Comment: Yea sorry, I realised after posting the mContext and constructor there wasn't actually needed. Although it did work fine when I tested, I had the FragmentDialog in a inner static class.

Comment: I think you must call the dismiss() method of the fragment instead of the dialog.

Answer (score 12):

> So, what's the simplest way to create and display a really basic Alert
>   Dialog? Bonus points if it's using the support library.

Simply create a `DialogFragment`(SDK or support library) and override its `onCreateDialog` method to return an `AlertDialog` with the desired text and buttons set on it:

```
public static class SimpleDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                .setNegativeButton("No way", null)
                .create();
    }

}
```

To do something when the user uses one of the buttons you'll have to provide an instance of a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` instead of the `null` references from my code.

Answer (score 5):

For those coding with Kotlin and [Anko](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/advanced-features-of-anko/), you can now do dialogs in 4 lines of code:

```
alert("Order", "Do you want to order this item?") {
    positiveButton("Yes") { processAnOrder() }
    negativeButton("No") { }
}.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

**because of Activity / Fragment lifecycle** **@athor & @lugsprog approach can fail,**
more elegant way is to **get activity context from method onAttach and store it as weak reference ** (&try to avoid non default constructor in DialogFragment!, to pass any argument to dialog use arguments) like this:

```
public class NotReadyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static String DIALOG_ARGUMENTS = "not_ready_dialog_fragment_arguments";

    private WeakReference<Context> _contextRef;

    public NotReadyDialogFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /** example pulling of arguments */
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle!=null) {
            bundle.get(DIALOG_ARGUMENTS);
        }

        //
        // Caution !!!
        // check we can use contex - by call to isAttached 
        // or by checking stored weak reference value itself is not null 
        // or stored in context -> example allowCreateDialog() 
        // - then for example you could throw illegal state exception or return null 
        //
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_contextRef.get());
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("...");
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Przerwij", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        _contextRef = new WeakReference<Context>(activity);
    }

     boolean allowCreateDialog() {
         return _contextRef !== null 
                && _contextRef.get() != null;
     }
```

**EDIT:**
& if You wanna dismiss dialog then:

1. try to get it
2. check if it's exist
3. check if it's showing
4. dismiss

something like this :

```
        NotReadyDialogFragment dialog = ((NotReadyDialogFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyDialogTag"));
    if (dialog != null) {
        Dialog df = dialog.getDialog();
        if (df != null && df.isShowing()) {
            df.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT2:** & if u wanna set dialog as non cancelable u should change onCreatweDialog return statement like this:

```
    /** convert builder to dialog */
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    /** disable cancel outside touch */
    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    /** disable cancel on press back button */
    setCancelable(false);

    return alert;
```

Comment: So I understand that calling `getActivity()` in the constructor can fail, but why would the solution suggested by Luksprog fail? Calling `getActivity()` in `onCreateDialog()` is exactly what the default implementation does, storing my own reference to the context sounds like the opposite of what I want to be doing.

Comment: @Thorbear getActivity() could return null when fragment is not attached to activity - you can use it but you should check it - sam for example using getResources() in fragment while fragment is not attached

Comment: Yes, and usually (always) the fragment is not attached when the constructor is being called. But is there any situation where `onCreateDialog()` will be called while the fragment is not attached? Again, the default implementation (the support library) calls `getActivity()` in `onCreateDialog()` without checking for null, are you saying that it should?