# Relationship between DialogFragment and DialogInterface

Tags: android, android-fragments

`DialogFragment` does not not implement `DialogInterface` and this rocks the foundations of how I assumed Dialogs work.

Where can I find out more about the internals of the dialog system and where does the DialogInterface come from?

Answer (score -1):

You should implement `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` on your own and with your needs see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912181/simplest-yes-no-dialog-fragment)