# WebView Error on Navigation View with Fragment

Tags: android, webview, navigation, fragment

I am making a simple application but getting error, here is my
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.intawebapp.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import com.example.intawebapp.R;
import com.example.intawebapp.fragment.HomeFragment;
import com.example.intawebapp.fragment.NotificationsFragment;
import com.example.intawebapp.fragment.SettingsFragment;
import com.example.intawebapp.other.CircleTransform;
import com.example.intawebapp.fragment.PortalFragment;
import com.example.intawebapp.fragment.ESSFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    WebView myWebView;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private View navHeader;
    private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
    private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    // urls to load navigation header background image
    // and profile image
    private static final String urlNavHeaderBg = "http://example.com/nav-menu-header-bg.jpg";
    private static final String urlProfileImg = "http://example.com/prof";

    // index to identify current nav menu item
    public static int navItemIndex = 0;

    // tags used to attach the fragments
    private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";

    private static final String TAG_PORTAL = "portal";
    private static final String TAG_ESS = "ess";

    private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
    private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
    public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

    // toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
    private String[] activityTitles;

    // flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
    private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
    private Handler mHandler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        // Navigation view header
        navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
        imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
        imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());


        // load toolbar titles from string resources
        activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        // load nav menu header data
        loadNavHeader();

        // initializing navigation menu
        setUpNavigationView();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
        }
    }

    /***
     * Load navigation menu header information
     * like background image, profile image
     * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
     */
    private void loadNavHeader() {
        // name, website
        txtName.setText("My Name");
        txtWebsite.setText("www.example.com");

        // loading header background image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

        // Loading profile image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                .crossFade()
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfile);

        // showing dot next to notifications label
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
    }

    /***
     * Returns respected fragment that user
     * selected from navigation menu
     */
    private void loadHomeFragment() {
        // selecting appropriate nav menu item
        selectNavMenu();

        // set toolbar title
        setToolbarTitle();

        // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
        // just close the navigation drawer
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();

            // show or hide the fab button
            toggleFab();
            return;
        }

        // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
        // when switching between navigation menus
        // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
        // This effect can be seen in GMail app
        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };

        // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }

        // show or hide the fab button
        toggleFab();

        //Closing drawer on item click
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // refresh toolbar menu
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
        switch (navItemIndex) {
            case 0:
                // home
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                return homeFragment;
            case 1:
                // portal
                PortalFragment portalFragment = new PortalFragment();
                return portalFragment;
            case 2:
                // ESS fragment
                ESSFragment essFragment = new ESSFragment();
                return essFragment;
            case 3:
                // notifications fragment
                NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                return notificationsFragment;

            case 4:
                // settings fragment
                SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                return settingsFragment;
            default:
                return new HomeFragment();
        }
    }

    private void setToolbarTitle() {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
    }

    private void selectNavMenu() {
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            myWebView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void setUpNavigationView() {
        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.home:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_portal:
                        navItemIndex = 1;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PORTAL;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_ess:
                        navItemIndex = 2;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_ESS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_notifications:
                        navItemIndex = 3;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        navItemIndex = 4;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_about_us:
                        // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_exit:
                        // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExitActivity.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                }

                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                loadHomeFragment();

                return true;
            }
        });


        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }

        // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
        // when user is in other fragment than home
        if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
            // checking if user is on other navigation menu
            // rather than home
            if (navItemIndex != 0) {
                navItemIndex = 0;
                CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                loadHomeFragment();
                return;
            }
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        // show menu only when home fragment is selected
        if (navItemIndex == 0) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        }

        // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for notifications
        if (navItemIndex == 3) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        // user is in notifications fragment
        // and selected 'Mark all as Read'
        if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All notifications marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // user is in notifications fragment
        // and selected 'Clear All'
        if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clear all notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // show or hide the fab
    private void toggleFab() {
        if (navItemIndex == 0)
            fab.show();
        else
            fab.hide();
    }
}
```

and this is my AboutUsActivity

```
package com.example.intawebapp.activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.intawebapp.R;

public class AboutUsActivity extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public AboutUsActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static AboutUsActivity newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        AboutUsActivity fragment = new AboutUsActivity();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_about_us, container, false);
    }


    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
//        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
//            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
//        } else {
//            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
//                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
//        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error when I choose About from the menu

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.intawebapp, PID: 8170
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.intawebapp/com.example.intawebapp.activity.AboutUsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.intawebapp.activity.AboutUsActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.intawebapp.activity.AboutUsActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.
```

I need help to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class))` – `AboutUsActivity` is not an `Activity`, despite the name. It's a `Fragment`. You'll need to learn the difference, and change how you handle that depending on which you want it to be.

Comment: I want when I click the About menu it will show a small window showing logo and my name and if i touch anywhere or touch the back button it will disappear.

Comment: Then you probably want `AboutUsActivity` to `extends DialogFragment` instead, and you should change the class name accordingly; e.g., `AboutUsFragment`. You would then use its `show()` method to display it, rather than `startActivity()`, which is only used with `Activity` subclasses. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12912181).